# User profiles cleanup problem - bdeleted does not change to 1

Tags: user-profile-service-app

In my environment there is UPSA, Active Directory connection created and profiles already imported. When I deleted one of imported account in Active Directory and run UPA Full Sync the account was not removed from SharePoint profiles - which is expected behaviour! The problem is that the account is not being marked to be deleted. I checked 'UserProfle_Full' table in UPSA db and recognized that 'bdeleted' did not change to 1.

[image]

The good is that 'IsImported' has changed from 1 to 0 but why 'bDeleted' remained on 0?

I tried also just disable account in AD and the result was the same (I use LDAP filter (&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)) in UPA Sync connection and I'm sure it works correctly).

My farm version - 16.0.4600.1001 (October 2017 CU installed)

Has anybody faced this problem or can advise how to troubleshoot it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User Profiles using AD Import are never removed automatically. Instead, run the following.

```
$proxy = Get-SPServiceApplicationProxy | ?{$_.TypeName -match 'profile'}
Set-SPProfileServiceApplication $proxy -PurgeNonImportedObjects:$true
```

If you want the previous behavior of the UPSS, implement MIM.

Comment: Hi Trevor,

Thank you for reply.

I'd like to use functionality of the 'Mysite cleanup job' and as I know the action is taken when 'bdeleted = 1'. Should it be still the case in SP2016 that if Full Sync does not "see" an account in Active Directory any more, bdeleted is setting to 1?

Comment: AD Import has never removed profiles. If you need to leverage the My Site cleanup job and do not want to rely on running the above PowerShell, then you need to implement Microsoft Identity Manager.